# Linear Algebra, Condition Number

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having trouble to prove the two equalities below with condition number

i) $K_a(A)\geq1$ for $A$ invertible
ii)$K_F(I)=n$

For i) $K_a(A)=||A||_{(a)}+||A^{-1}||_{(a)}$ and $||A||_{(a)}=max(||Ax||_a;||x||_a=1)$ but I do not know what to do in any of the equations.

Comment: @ askasy , this homework has a straightforward proof under the condition that you correctly write the definition of "condition number". Look at wikipedia (if this is not too tiring).

Comment: @loupblanc I look at wikipedia but I could not see this direct proof

Comment: @ askazy , you are not serious. $K(A)=||A||||A^{-1}||$ where $||.||$ is an induced norm. For i) use $AA^{-1}=I$. For ii), calculate, with hand, the Frobenius norm of $I$.